# The D3.js graph freezes when sending another XMLHTTPRequest to the servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, d3.js

I am having a problem with the nodes generated in `D3.js`. I am having an `HTML` file where the Force directed graph is viewed, and a simple `Java servlet` to receive `Get` request from the browser via `XMLHttpPrequest`. When I insert anything in the text area and click on the "Find" button on the `HTML` page, I send an `XMLHttpRequest` to the Servlet and get one single data represented as a node in `D3.js`. It is working correctly. When I click on the "Find" button again with the same text or another text in the text area, the generated node does not move anymore. Here is my code:

The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>

.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="find" size="20"/>
<button type="button" onclick='find();'> Find Tutorials </button></br>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"></script>

<script>
var xmlHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var obj;
var array = new Array();

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var width = 960,
height = 500;

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

function process()
{
if (xmlHTTPRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTPRequest.status == 200)
{
    obj = JSON.parse(xmlHTTPRequest.responseText);  
array.push(obj);
init();
}
}

function init()
{
  force
  .nodes(array)
  .start();

   var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(array)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return 1; })
  .call(force.drag);

   node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
 });
}

function find()
{
xmlHTTPRequest.open("GET", "/SampleServlet/MyServlet?find=" + document.getElementById("findAuthor").value, true);
xmlHTTPRequest.onreadystatechange = process;
xmlHTTPRequest.send(null);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Java Servlet:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String findAuthor = request.getParameter("find");

    if (findAuthor!= null)
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().write(generateJSON(find));
    }
}
    public String generateJSON(String topicName) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        JSONSerialisation json = new JSONSerialisation();
        StringBuffer returnData = null;
        if(topicName.equals("java"))
        {
                            String str = "java";
                            String parsedString = json.getString(str.toString());
            returnData = new StringBuffer("{\"name\":");
            returnData.append(parsedString);
            returnData.append("}");
        }
        return returnData.toString();
    }
```

Could anyone please help me solve and find the reason why this node is not moving when sending another XMLHttpRequest. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you made your XMLHttpRequest a global object and defined it with `var`:

```
<script>
var xmlHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Instead, either create a new XMLHttpRequest inside the *function* that does the Ajax call, and do not explicitly use `var`. I think its also bad for readability to make the variable name look so much like the constructor you call to create it:

```
function find()
{
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ...
```

or (the better option) use a framework like [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) to do your Ajax calls instead of using XMLHttpRequest directly.  This is the better option for several reasons, including that you should be checking browser compatibility and using different methods for different browsers, like:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

A framework will do this stuff for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I defined that request inside the find function. Unfortunately, it says that there is an error as the XMLHTTPRequest is not defined. It seems I must add "var". Do you think I should not create create two different functions for getting the request done?

Comment: By the way, thank you for suggesting me the JQuery option. I have started using it. Every Ajax call, I get one node on the browser. My problem now is when I make three calls, the first and second nodes do not move but the third which has just generated can move. I do not know why.